# Endomorphism ring of Drinfeld module of rank 1

Tags: nt.number-theory

That the endomorphism ring of a Drinfeld $A$-module of rank 1 is isomorphic to $A$ appears as a corollary to the more general result that a Drinfeld module of rank $r$ has endomorphism ring of rank at most $r^2$ (a result obtained by analyzing the map 
$\text{Hom}(\phi,\psi)\otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p}}\to\text{Hom}(T_{\mathfrak{p}}(\phi),T_{\mathfrak{p}}(\psi))$).  Without using this more general result or the uniformization theorem for Drinfeld modules, is there a way to get a more direct handle on $\text{End}(\phi)$ when $\phi$ is of rank 1?

Answer (score 3):

We can construct a new object from $O:=\text{End}(\phi)$ by looking at $\psi:O\to \mathscr{F} \{ \tau \}$ defined by $\psi_f = f$.  This thing is not automatically a Drinfeld module, but it is close.

We can either relax our definition of Drinfeld modules or use an isogeny to assume that $\psi$ is a Drinfeld module (See the proof of **Proposition 4.7.17** in *Basic Structures of Function Field Arithmetic* by Goss and *Explicit Class Field Theory of Global Function Fields* by Hayes).

Now, by looking at the torsion $\psi[a]$ for some $a\in A$ (we need to be a little careful here if $\psi$ is not really a Drinfeld module), we can see that the rank of $\psi$ is less than that of $\phi$ and also that $O$ is equal to $A$.

EDIT: I forgot to say that if $\text{End}(\phi)$ is not commutative you may have to look at a commutative subring, just like in **Proposition 4.7.17** of Goss' book.